# Eclipse Tomcat Configuration Documentation/example page 404

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Now I've installed Tomcat successfully in my Windows 7. In cmd, I can start the server and get to the Tomcat homepage. Also, I can successfully access the doc, example pages etc.

But for Eclipse, I can successfully get the Tomcat homepage, which is localhost:8080.
[image: Homepage in Eclipse]

However, if I just click the Documentation at the top in the home page, I will get HTTP Status 404 Error. Same errors happen on examples, etc.

Here is the configuration of the server.[image: Configuration of server]

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the server location to point to the tomcat installation directory rather than the custom directory.